# Proof of white noise expansion in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, random-variables, stochastic-analysis

We're reading through Da Prato/Zabczyk's proof of the existence of a white noise expansion of Gaussian measures and there's a step where we are stuck:

Theorem 2.12 [Da Prato/Zabczyk, Stochastic equations in infinite dimensions]

Let $\mu$ be a symmetric Gaussian measure on a separable Banach space $E$ and let $H_\mu$ be its reproducing kernel space. Let $\{e_n\}$ be an orthonormal and complete baasis in $H_\mu$ and $\{\xi_n\}$ a sequence of independent real valued random variables such that $\mathcal{L}(\xi_n) = \mathcal N(0,1), n\in \mathbb N$. Then the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \xi_k e_k$ converges $\mathbb P$-a.s. in $E$ and 
$$ \mathcal L \Big(\sum_{k=1}^\infty\xi_k e_k\Big) = \mu.$$
Proof:

As Gaussians have finite second moments, we write $\bar E^*$ as the closure of $E^*$ in $L^2(E,\mathcal B(E), \mu)$ and $\phi_n\in \bar E^*$ such that $J\phi_n = e_n$, where $J:\bar E^* \to E$ with $J(\phi) = \int_E x\phi(x) \mu(dx)$ the map that defines $H_\mu = J(E)$.

We can assume that the sequence $\{\phi_n\}$ is linearly dense in $\bar E^*$ [first question: Why?]. Note that the real random variables $\phi_n$ are independent and $\mathcal N(0,1)$ distributed. Our aim is to show that 
$$ x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \phi_k(x)e_k \text{ for $\mu$-almost all $x\in E$.}$$
Let $$\mu_n = \mathcal L\Big(\sum_{k=1}^n \xi_ke_k\Big), n\in \mathbb N.$$
We prove first that the sequence $\{\mu_n\}$ is tight. Denote $S(x)=x$ and 
$$S_N(x) = \sum_{n=1}^N\phi_n(x)e_n = \sum_{n=1}^N\phi_n(x) J\phi_n, x\in E.$$
For arbitrary $\phi \in E^*$ the sequence 
$$\phi(S_N(x)) = \sum_{n=1}^N\phi_n(x)\phi(e_n)$$
is $\mu$-almost surely convergent because
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty|\phi(e_n)|^2  = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\langle J\phi,e_n\rangle_{H_\mu}^2 = |J\phi|_{H_\mu}^2 < \infty$$

[Next question]
We don't understand how the almost sure convergence can be proved that way: We tried to show the summability of the second moments by using Cauchy-Schwartz:
$$\sum_{n=1}^N |\phi_n(x)\phi(e_n)|^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^N |\phi_n(x)|^2 \cdot\sum_{n=1}^N |\phi(e_n)|^2$$

The second sum is bounded as mentioned, but the first sum seems to be an unbounded sum of variances of independent real normal random variables, which sums to $N$ for fixed $N$.

Answer (score 0):

Q1: If $\mu$ is supported by a subspace of $E$, then there will be non-trivial elements of $E^*$that (viewed as random variables on $E$) vanish $\mu$-a.e. The associated elements of $H_\mu$ will then be $0$.  It seems to me that the "we can assume..." amounts to the assumption that the support of $\mu$ is all of $E$, and this assumption entails no real loss of generality.

Q2: Isn't this just (the mean zero,  finite variance special case of) Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem: If independent random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ satisfy $E(X_n)=0$ and $\sum_n E(X_n^2)<\infty$, then $\sum_n X_k$ converges a.s. (and of course also in $L^2$). For a quick proof, the partial sums $S_n:=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ form an $L^2$-bounded martingale.

Comment: To Q2: We also found that theorem which explains why we need to calculate the sum of squares in the first place, but our problem is the boundedness of first term, which we really don't see.